# Understanding EF Code-First eager-loading

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I've been working with EF CodeFirst since EF 4.1 went live, that's more than a year ago, and I feel pretty confortable working with it now. I'm used to custom entity validators, overriding .SaveChanges() to modify some of it's behaviours and to some non-trivial concepts like mapping to nontable db objects. But theres this part of EF that remain cloudy to me: `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`.

I understand the basics, linq queries will be thrown to the database as soon as they are called, dependent collections won't get loaded if I don't explicitly specify it, yadda yadda yadda.
What I would love to understand is:

- In what situations should I disable lazy loading? And why?
- What are the practical benefits and/or drawbacks of disabling it?
- Any additional clarification is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF v1 did not support lazy loading. When lazy loading was added in the 2nd round (it was EF4) it could cause problems when porting apps written with EF v1 to EF4 when suddenly a lot more queries would have been sent to the database when it had not happen before. Therefore the easiest way to make a EF v1 work on EF4 was to disable lazy loading.

Another interesting thing is to take a look at how lazy loading is implemented - EF will dynamically create a type derived from your entity type and will add some code to handle lazy loading. This means that EF is not actually using your type but the type derived from your type. This is usually OK but sometimes may cause issues.

Finally sometimes you may want to control when queries are actually sent to the database (e.g. due to latency when using Sql Azure it is usually better/faster to send one query returning a bigger result instead of a lot of queries returning smaller results). With lazy loading it often happens the people don't realize that they hit the database hard when it is not necessary or not effective. One thing to notice here that you can mix both worlds - .Include() will force loading related entities regardless of the lazy loading setting.

You may read more about this here: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-look-at-lazy-loading-in-ef4/ and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx

Comment: What about filtered DbSets? Does eager/lazy loading plays any part in it?

Comment: I am not sure what you are refering to as filtered DbSets. Lazy loading is done for navigation properties.